# Processing several generators in parallel

Tags: python

Suppose I have several generators (which should be able to run in parallel). Is it possible to use multiprocessing module to call next() on these generators so that the processing would run in parallel?

I want to avoid making a list from the generators since it's very likely to consume lots of memory.

**Context**: Originally I have a generator which outputs all spanning trees of a given graph. Part of the algorithm involves iterating through the power set of a subset of the neighbors of a given vertex. I would like to parallelize this part, at least for the initial call. For a certain graph, it takes around half a second to output a tree for the first 1024 trees.

Comment: So far as I'm aware, it's possible. Have you tried it? Do you have a specific problem in trying to get it to work?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do and it looks like multiprocessing might not be the right solution. Why dont you show a short example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @B.Eckles my problem with running it in parallel was that Process/Pool refuses to have a generator object passed to it due to generators not being picklable. But seeing the current answer, I realized that I can simply pass the generator parameters instead and let the child process put the results in a queue.

Answer (score 1):

I think your main issue would be getting the data base to the parent process to build your graph. However, this could probably be accomplished by using a multiprocessing [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue).

A simple example:

```
import multiprocessing
from queue import Empty

def call_generator(generator, queue):
    for item in generator:
        queue.put(item)

def process_responses(queue):
    items = []
    while True:
        try:
            # After a one second timeout, we'll assume the generators are done
            item = queue.get(timeout=1)
        except Empty:
            print('done')
            break

        print('item: {}'.format(item))

generators = [
    iter(range(10)),
    iter(range(11, 20)),
    iter(range(20, 50))
]

queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_responses, args=(queue,))
p.start()


for generator in generators:
    generator_process = multiprocessing.Process(
        target=call_generator,
        args=(generator, queue)
    )
    generator_process.start()

p.join() # Wait for process_response to return
```

Comment: Wouldn't Process refuse generator objects as arguments due to generators being not picklable? I didn't think of using queues though to put the results in; I'm new to the multiprocessing module and was toying around with Pools instead.

Comment: (didn't know enter key adds comment automatically) I think this could be solved with passing the parameters to the generator to the child process instead?

Comment: Well, I did test this code, and it did work. But sure, you could definitely structure it with a different target for each process. 

Pools would be fine as well. However, even if you use pools, you still need to somehow return the data from the generators to the parent process—and that would probably need to happen over a queue, pipe, shared memory, etc.